# So, there's an assignment in the MITx Python course that is giving me quite a bit of trouble

Tags: python

I'm sorry in advance for the noobishness. I'm very new to this whole thing. Like, has-been-only-doing-this-for-four-days new.

*clears throat* Anyway, I am dealing with the assignment "Exercise: vara varb" in the course "6.00.1x Introduction to Computer Science and Programming Using Python" by MITx. It is causing me quite a bit of trouble.

> Assume that two variables, varA and varB, are assigned values, either numbers or strings.
>
> Write a piece of Python code that evaluates varA and varB, and then prints out one of the following messages:
>
> "string involved" if either varA or varB are strings
>
> "bigger" if varA is larger than varB
>
> "equal" if varA is equal to varB
>
> "smaller" if varA is smaller than varB

Comment: You have to at least show what you've tried and day exactly where you're getting stuck.

Comment: Ok. What kind of trouble? You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: @JJJ My apologies. Um...

My latest attempt used this piece of code:

>if type(varA)==str or type(varB)==str:
>    print("string involved")
>elif varA>varB: 
>    print('bigger')
>elif varA==varB: 
>    print('equal')
>elif varA<varB: 
>    print('smaller')

It came back with, at first, syntax errors, and then "failed to define variable" errors. For reference, the assignment requires you to assume the grader code defines the variables.

Comment: Sounds like you need to read through some python tutorials. Maybe try http://learnpython.org/

Comment: Using len() function will be a solution for checking larger or lesser ex: len(varA) > len(varB)

Comment: @TheMyon please edit your question and put your code there, as you can see code in comments is unformatted, so it is hard to see where your error is (especially because indenting is crucial element of Python syntax). At the first glance, you're close to solving the problem.

Comment: @ChetanVasudevan len wouldn't tell you if the variable is a string or integer, so it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Replace A and B with values.

```
A = Value
B = Value

try:
    if A < B:
        print('smaller')
    elif A > B:
        print('bigger')
    elif A == B:
        print('equal')
except(TypeError,ValueError):
    print('string involved')
```

If you want to assign random values, you could use:

```
import random
import string

def find_value():
    num = random.randrange(1,3)
    if num == 1:
        characters = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
        x = ''
        for num3 in range(6): # six letters
            num2 = random.randrange(0,26)
            x = x + characters[num2]
            return x
    elif num == 2:
        x = random.randrange(0,101) #between 0 through 101, never 0 and 101
        return x

A = find_value()
B = find_value()

try:
    if A < B:
        print('smaller')
    elif A > B:
        print('bigger')
    elif A == B:
        print('equal')
except(TypeError,ValueError):
    print('string involved')
```

You could also have it repeat infinitely.

```
import random
import string
import time

def find_value():
    num = random.randrange(1,3)
    if num == 1:
        characters = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
        x = ''
        for num3 in range(6): # six letters
            num2 = random.randrange(0,26)
            x = x + characters[num2]
            return x
    elif num == 2:
        x = random.randrange(0,101) #between 0 through 101, never 0 and 101
        return x

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    A = find_value()
    B = find_value()

    try:
        if A < B:
            print('smaller')
        elif A > B:
            print('bigger')
        elif A == B:
            print('equal')
    except(TypeError,ValueError):
        print('string involved')
```

Comment: You should catch  ValueError not TypeError since type is str for any input.

Comment: Try setting A='abc' and B=5 and see.

Comment: @MrGeek I got 'string invovled'

Comment: Don't set them in the code, read them, input them in the interpreter and you'll get 'bigger'.

Comment: @MrGeek I added both ValueError and TypeError to be caught. So now I get string involved

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153532/discussion-between-pokestar-fan-and-mr-geek).

Comment: There is no need for TypeError, because all the inputs in Python are strings, so if you have `A = input()` and you input `5` the type of A isn't a number, it's a string.

Comment: @MrGeek Check the previous comment

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution :

```
varA = input("A : ")
varB = input("B : ")
try: # to avoid errors when converting strings that have non-digits to numbers
  varA = float(varA)
  varB = float(varB)
  if varA > varB:
    print("bigger")
  elif varA < varB:
    print("smaller")
  else:
    print("equal")
except ValueError: # that means that python couldn't convert one of the variables to a number, which means it's a string
  print("string involved")
```